# javac: invalid flag: -Xlint:-sunapi | JDK 9

Tags: javac, java-9

Arguments passed to `javac` are as follows:

```
[javac] Using modern compiler
[javac] Compilation arguments:
[javac] '-deprecation'
[javac] '-d'
[javac] '..'
[javac] '-classpath'
[javac] '..'
[javac] '-sourcepath'
[javac] '..'
[javac] '-g'
[javac] '-XDenableSunApiLintControl'
[javac] '-Xlint:-sunapi'
```

Which results in error:

```
[javac] javac: invalid flag: -Xlint:-sunapi
```

Passing `-XDenableSunApiLintControl -Xlint:-sunapi` do work with JDK 8 and below. How do I get this to work with Java 9?

---

*Note: classpaths are removed for brevity.*